# Evaluate a number in (a few) natural language

Tags: prolog

Assume a list, each element can be:

a) a number 1,2,...9

b) a number 10, 100, 10000, ... (numbers of the form 10^(2^n) with n>=0).

It is need a (as much simple as possible) rule that evaluates this list to one integer number. Examples of this evaluation are:

```
[1] => 1
[2] => 2
[10 1] => 11
[2 10 1] => 21
[2 100 1 10 4] => 214
[2 10 1 100 4] => 2104
[2 10 1 100 10000] => 21000000
```

In other words, numbers 10, 100, ... are the equivalent of tenths, hundreds, million, ... in english and the rule to evaluate is the usual in english and other languages: 10, 100 "multiplies" the values before them, numbers after them are added.

(I know this definition is not an exact one, but finding a good definition is part of the problem. Do not hesitate to requests for more examples if necessary).

Note than, in the same way than in natural language, the number zero is not necessary. Even, like initial languages, is not present in the grammar.

**Addendum**

The major difficulty in this problem is an expression like [2 10000 3 10] that can not be taken as (2*10000+3)*10, but as 2*10000+3*10. Another example is [2 10 1 10000 3 10] that is (2*10+1)*10000+3*10.

Proof of not homework: Interest on this numbering (and, in general, in natural language) is that, in some context, they are more error-safe than binary. By example, in a context of a supermarket prices, "two thousands blah" keeps some meaning, while 1001blah is totally undefined.

Comment: What is Prolog specific to this problem? Seems to be exactly the same in other languages, too.

Comment: @MrLister: Roman numbers was purely additive. Not applicable to this case (in fact, theoricals of numbers think they was a variant of unary).

Comment: @false: of course, after finding a set of rules. they can be implemented in any language. But, in general, prolog is a way to express rules and ideas more clear than, by example, C/C++ or Java.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: No, nothing nice to show. But do not worry, this is not homework ;-)

Comment: Roman numbers are not completely additive: ⅠↃ = 500, ⅭⅠↃ = 1000, ⅭⅭⅠↃↃ = 10000, ⅭⅭⅭⅠↃↃↃ = 100000

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: I do not see much ambiguity (that's where Prolog is very good at). In fact, ⅭⅠↃ is ambiguous in some sense. It could be 400 or (as it actually is) 1000.

Comment: @false: yes, it is true, latter evolution of roman numbers added some multiplicative aspects, like the ones you describe. However, we can easily see why they are not a numbering system equivalent to the one described in this question. In roman numbers, 21 is XXI, while in this "language" is [2 10 1], or "two tenths and one", that we could "romanice" as 2X1 .

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: should also [7,7,7] be a valid representation of 21? Then, it would start to become, interesting (that is Prolog-like).

Comment: @false: no, 21 is always [2 10 1] (and, in my opinion, Prolog is also interesting in the areas of DCG's, handling of recursive data estructures, ...) with a syntax and characteristics not found in other paradigms.

Comment: *The major difficulty in this problem is an expression like [2 10000 3 10] that can not be taken as (2*10000+3)*10, but as 2*10000+3*10*. I don't understand this statement. It seems to contradict the definition implied by your examples. Your examples seem to imply that `[2 10000 3 10]` should evaluate as `(2*10000+3)*10`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @luker: thanks for your interest. When, in english, we say "two thousands four tenths" (two thousands fourty) we interpret as 2*1000+4*10. In the same way [2 10000 4 10] is 20040 in this problem: 2<=>two, 10000<=>thousand(!), 4<=>four, 10<=>tenths.

Answer (score 3):

With ingenuity, I would start covering the patterns...

```
test :- forall(member(L=R, [
    [1] = 1,
    [2] = 2,
    [10, 1] = 11,
    [2, 10, 1] = 21,
    [2, 100, 1, 10, 4] = 214,
    [2, 10, 1, 100, 4] = 2104,
    [2, 10, 1, 100, 10000] = 21000000
    ]), test(L, R)).

test(L, R) :-
    pattern(L, E), R =:= E -> writeln(ok(L,R)) ; writeln(ko(L,R)).

pattern([A], A) :- dig(A).
pattern([A, B], A+B) :- ten(A), dig(B).
pattern([A, B, C], A*B+C) :- mul_ten(A, B), dig(C).

pattern([A, B, C, D, E], A*B + C*D + E) :- mul_ten(A,B), mul_ten(C,D), B > D, dig(E).
pattern([A, B, C, D, E], ((A*B+C)*D)+E) :- mul_ten(A,B), ten(D), dig(E). % doubt...
pattern([A, B, C, D, E], (A*B+C)*D*E) :- mul_ten(A,B), ten(D), ten(E). % doubt...


dig(D) :- between(1,9,D).
ten(T) :- between(0,10,E), T =:= 10^(2^E). % 10 -> inappropriate (too much zeroes ?)
mul_ten(M,T) :- between(1,9,M), ten(T).    % 9 -> inappropriate ?
```

plain pattern matching. Running:

```
?- test.
ok([1],1)
ok([2],2)
ok([10,1],11)
ok([2,10,1],21)
ok([2,100,1,10,4],214)
ok([2,10,1,100,4],2104)
ok([2,10,1,100,10000],21000000)
true.
```

I think that there is little space for recursion, afaik idioms cover frequently used cases, but without 'smart' evaluation... Anyway, I cannot really find my way in (that is, I would never use) this pattern

```
[2 10 1 100 4] => 2104
```

*edit* now, with DCG and CLP(FD) :

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

test :- forall(member(L=R, [
    [1] = 1,
    [2] = 2,
    [10, 1] = 11,
    [2, 10, 1] = 21,
    [2, 100, 1, 10, 4] = 214,
    [2, 10, 1, 100, 4] = 2104,
    [2, 10, 1, 100, 10000] = 21000000
    ]), test(L, R)).

test(L, R) :-
    phrase(pattern(E), L), R #= E -> writeln(ok(L,R)) ; writeln(ko(L,R)).

pattern(A) --> dig(A).
pattern(A+B) --> ten(A), dig(B).
pattern(A*B+C) --> mul_ten(A, B), dig(C).
pattern(A*B+C*D) --> mul_ten(A, B), mul_ten(C, D).
pattern(A*B + C*D + E) --> mul_ten(A,B), mul_ten(C,D), dig(E).
pattern(((A*B+C)*D)+E) --> mul_ten(A,B), [C], ten(D), dig(E). % doubt...
pattern((A*B+C)*D*E) --> mul_ten(A,B), [C], ten(D), ten(E). % doubt...

dig(D) --> [D], {D #>= 1, D #=< 9}.
ten(T) --> [T], {T #>= 1, T #= (10^(2^E)), E #> 0, E #=< 10}.
mul_ten(M,T) --> dig(M), ten(T).
```

*edit* I like the op/3 directive, also...

```
:- op(100,fx, dig).
:- op(100,fx, ten).
:- op(100,xfx, mul).

pattern(A) --> dig A.
pattern(A+B) --> ten A, dig B.
pattern(A*B+C) --> A mul B, dig(C).
pattern(A*B+C*D) --> A mul B, C mul D.
pattern(A*B+C*D+E) --> A mul B, C mul D, dig E.
pattern(((A*B+C)*D)+E) --> A mul B, [C], ten D, dig E. % doubt...
pattern((A*B+C)*D*E) --> A mul B, [C], ten D, ten E. % doubt...

dig D --> [D], {D #>= 1, D #=< 9}.
ten T --> [T], {T #>= 1, T #= (10^(2^E)), E #> 0, E #=< 10}.
M mul T --> dig M, ten T.
```

Comment: Quick nit: replace `10^(2^E)`  by `10^2^E`! Exponentiation is always right-associative. (Left associativity is futile)

Comment: And why `(#/\)/2`? We have `(',')/2` - have we not? The `(#/\)/2` is only useful for reified expressions.

Comment: Very nice answer, with some exemplar program resources like "test", usage of custom operators, ... . The only missing point to be a solution is that it is limited to expressions of maximum 5 items, and it seems a "pattern" must be defined for each possible combination of "mul's" and 'ten's" and 'dig's", something difficult to scalate to any length expressions.

Comment: I avoided recursion on purpose, since idiomatic constructs usually are not 'compositional'. IMHO, it's best to declare each pattern, so to restrict the semantic to well defined cases